# Does the numbing traps passive from multiple Demon Hunters stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The [numbing traps passive](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/numbing-traps) text reads:

```
Enemies you Slow or hit with Fan of Knives, Spike Trap, Caltrops, Grenades,
and Sentry fire have their damage reduced by 25% for 3 seconds.
```

Let's say you're in a game with 4 Demon Hunters, all running the numbing traps passive. Would the damage reduction from these passives stack? If so, I'm assuming they stack multiplicatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, these stack multiplicatively. Here is a [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/u49xl/psa_monks_crippling_wave_concussion_and_the/) with some empirical data testing a similar damage reduction from a monk.

Each one is assessed in some order determined by the game, so really the reduction for 4 players would be

```
damage = total * (1 - 0.25) * (1 - 0.25) * (1 - 0.25) * (1 - 0.25)
```

Which means the total damage reduction is going to be

```
1 - (0.75^4) = 0.68359375
```

Which is is roughly `68.4%` from 4 stacks of 25% damage reduction.

25% reduction for 1-4 players:

- 1: 25%
- 2: 43.8%
- 3: 57.8%
- 4: 68.4%